# Custom filter doesnt work

Tags: php, filter, yii2, case

I have a problem with my CASE part of my script (third $query). I'm creating filter which filters an interval between shifts. I don't know wheres the problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
        } elseif ($this->shift == DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT) { //druga zmiana
        $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', "(cast(to_char(".Production::tableName().'."created_at"'.", 'HH') as int))" , DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_START_HOUR]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['<', "(cast(to_char(".Production::tableName().'."created_at"'.", 'HH') as int))" , DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_HOUR]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['<=', "
                            (
                                CASE
                                    cast(to_char(".Production::tableName().'."created_at"'.", 'HH') as int)
                                WHEN
                                    ".DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_HOUR."
                                THEN (cast(to_char(".Production::tableName().'."created_at"'.", 'MI') as int))
                                ELSE -1
                            )
                            "
                                , DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_MINUTE]);
```

I have tried also in another way like:

```
            $query->andWhere("
                            CASE
                                cast(to_char(".Production::tableName().'."created_at"'.", 'HH') as int)
                            WHEN
                                ".DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_HOUR."
                            THEN
                            ((cast(to_char(".Production::tableName().'."created_at"'.", 'MI') as int)) <= ".DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_MINUTE. ")");
```

It should work like: If rows created_at belongs to an interval and `DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_HOUR`== rows created_at hour, then compare `DeliveryItem::SECOND_SHIFT_END_MINUTE` with rows_created_at minute and filter it.

Regards

Comment: which db you are using ???'

Comment: I'm using postgres